# Computational complexity of maximizing sum of rational functions

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, optimization, np-hard, integer-programming

I have a optimization problem:

$$\max_z\ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{W_i}{D_i - z_i} \quad \text{s.t.}\ \sum_{i=1}^n z_i \leq k, z_i \in [0,k],$$ where each $W_i$, $D_i$ are constants and $z_i$ are integer variables. Assume each $D_i >k$.

The optimal solution obviously satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^n z_i =k$.
But it seems there is no efficient way to get the optimum other than trying out all partitions.

Also, I know the above problem can be formulated as linear integer programming.

Is there any hint of proving the hardness of the above problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved in polynomial time.

Suppose $n-2$ variables (without loss of generality, say $z_3,\ldots,z_n$) are fixed, then the objective becomes maximizing $$\frac{W_1}{D_1-z_1}+\frac{W_2}{D_2-z_2}$$ where $z_1+z_2\le k-(z_3+\cdots+z_n):=K$. Let $$f(z)=\frac{W_1}{D_1-z}+\frac{W_2}{D_2-(K-z)}, 0\le z\le K,$$
then
$$f''(z)=\frac{2W_1}{(D_1-z)^3}+\frac{2W_2}{(D_2-K+z)^3}\ge0,$$
which means $f(z)$ is convex on $[0,K]$, thus the maximum value is achieved at either $z=0$ or $z=K$. This suggests that we can adjust an optimal solution such that either $z_1=0$ or $z_2=0$.

We can repeat this adjustment until there are only one non-zero variable among $z_1,\ldots,z_n$. So to solve your primary problem, just try the solutions $(k,0,\ldots,0),(0,k,\ldots,0),\ldots,(0,\ldots,0,k)$ and choose the optimal one among them.

Comment: Alternatively, use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @xskxzr I think there is a problem in your analysis. f(z) is convex but not necessarily monotone. The maximum value is not necessarily at z=0 or z=K. In fact, I have run some simulations and find that optimal solutions might be (0,0,..,k_1,...,0,0,k_2,...,0,0)

Comment: @Paradox The conclusion that the maximum value is achieved at z=0 or z=K does not require f(z) to be monotone. If f(z) is not monotone, it must first decrease then increase.